How to change the url from where Mason tries to install a package?
I am new to Neovim and I am trying to set up a Java lsp. I am having trouble installing jdtls from Mason. Every time I open up Neovim, Mason tries to install jdtls automatically and fails every time. I noticed the url from where it tries to download the files is wrong:
           mason.nvim
        press g? for help
     https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim

(1) All (2) LSP (3) DAP (4) Linter (5) Formatter

Language Filter: press <C-f> to apply filter

Failed (1)
    jdtls
        Displaying full log
        Downloading file "https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/1.31.0/jdt-language-server-1.31.0-202402151717.tar.gz"...
        spawn: wget failed      with exit code 8 and signal 0.
        Failed to download file "https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/1.31.0/jdt-language-server-1.31.0-202402151717.tar.gz".

Installed (10)
    black
    clang-format
    clangd
    codelldb
    eslint_d
    isort
    lua-language-server
    lua_ls
    prettier
    stylua
    typescript-language-server
    tsserver

Available (418)
    actionlint
    ada-language-server
    als
    alex
    angular-language-server
    angularls
    .
    .
    .

If you take a loot at the url https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/1.31.0/jdt-language-server-1.31.0-202402151717.tar.gz, you can see that the version 1.31.0 does not match with the number 202402151717. The version number is supposed to be 1.33.0. You can check for yourself on the website https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/?d. I am wondering where this url is set and how I could change it.
I am using WSL version: 2.1.5.0 on Windows11 and here's also 2 screenshots from my :checkhealth command:
https://i.sstatic.net/RgwhH.png
https://i.sstatic.net/Kc2dw.png
I've tried removing every single file I could find that has "jdtls" in its name, and Mason still persisted by trying to install from that wrong url. Also does Mason have some sort of cache? If so, how can I clear it? I've also tried taking a look at ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/registries/github/mason-org/mason-registry/registry.json as was suggested at https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1508, but there, I notice the version along with that number were correct. What I've managed to achieve was to start up Neovim, let Mason try to install jdtls (and fail), then delete every jdtls related file I could find that was installed by Mason and then manually type the command :MasonInstall jdtls, and it worked! Well, until I closed Neovim and reopened it again, and it tried to install jdtls from that same wrong link as if I haven't installed jdtls before.
I hope someone can help, thanks.

Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Yes, this bug still exists in the latest version of mason-lspconfig. I think when mason generates the url it gives the wrong filename because it will assume the filename with the timestamp of the last version.
e.g. i change in nvim-java required version of jdtls and now i have
https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/1.33.0/jdt-language-server-1.33.0-202404251256.tar.gz

before my change
https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/1.31.0/jdt-language-server-1.31.0-202404251256.tar.gz

and both this url's are wrong, but when you change to 1.35
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/jdtls/milestones/1.35.0/jdt-language-server-1.35.0-202404251256.tar.gz

then you can see that this url is ok, and common part of this url's is timestamp of file.

If i'm not wrong, that's because it's hard coded
https://github.com/mason-org/mason-registry/blob/8d9759754598c5345f4671573741459b2722ac8f/packages/jdtls/package.yaml#L2
